# How to add and use module in current app

Tags: android, android-studio

I follow the https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html to add 3 modules for my apps.

But after add these modules, i don't see any files in the source. 
I've also added Dependency for my main apps with these 3 modules. And i cannot reference any thing in the module.

What should i do to use the modules from Google?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you download these libraries from `Android SDK Manager`?

Please, follow the next steps:

Open the Android SDK Manager (`Tools > Android > SDK Manager`), and under `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`, select the `SDK Toolstab` to select and download:

`Google Play Licensing Library packageGoogle Play APK Expansion Library package`.

Create a new library module for the `License Verification Library and Downloader Library`.

For each library:

Select `File > New > New Module`.

In the `Create New Module window`, select `Android Library`, and then select `Next`.

Specify an `Application/Library name` such as `Google Play License Library` and `Google Play Downloader Library`.

Choose `Minimum SDK level`, then select `Finish`.

Select `File > Project Structure`.

Select the `Properties tab` and in `Library Repository`, enter the library from the `<sdk>/extras/google/directory (play_licensing/` for the License Verification Library or `play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/` for the Downloader Library).

Select `OK` to create the new module.

Comment: I followed all steps above. Downloaded the package and created the module. But i cannot import the package to use in my main apps. And i've checked the directory in the Project explore, it's empty as the above pictures. However, i open the package and there many source files inside it. The problem is my Gradle or Android Studio didn't compile it correctly or something so it didn't recognize the package.

Comment: Try to use "Runtime", instead of "Compile". If it won't help you, create a new project and repeat the steps above with this one.

Comment: I dont see "Runtime" option.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue:

1. Import module, not create module.
2. I only imported successfully with Play License Library and  APK Zip File. The Downloader Library cannot be imported if i don't follow the following trick:

   Open it's Project.Properties

   Remove the line: android.library.reference.1=../market_licensing And it works like a charm